# DECLARE statement make variables to be global?

Tags: t-sql, global-variables, sql-server-2012, declare, table-variable

Why DECLARE statement is making declared variables to be global?

For example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @LoopCounter TINYINT = 3

    WHILE @LoopCounter <> 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @TempDataSource TABLE ([ID] TINYINT)

        SELECT [ID]
        FROM @TempDataSource

        INSERT INTO @TempDataSource ([ID])
        VALUES (1)
              ,(2)
              ,(3)

        SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter - 1
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Gives me:

[image]

Should it returns nothing in all cases?

Comment: The scope of `@TempDataSource` is everything between the `GO`s.  It will not be re-declared with every iteration.

Comment: SQL Server does not have global/local variables. `The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.`

Comment: @MartinSmith But, is it natural if a DECLARE statement is executing several times, what was recorded in the variable to be lost, or maybe the Server is executing the DECLARE statement one time only?

Comment: The `DECLARE` isn't really executed at all as you seem to expect. Try `SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE name = 'gotqn';DECLARE @T TABLE(gotqn INT)`. You see the table variable is actually created already before the `DECLARE` is even encountered.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the references and comments. This make sense.

Comment: Related: [How do I drop table variables in SQL-Server? Should I even do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653520/how-do-i-drop-table-variables-in-sql-server-should-i-even-do-this)

Comment: @MartinSmith I just wanted to add that the discussion above is not valid for temp tables.  SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE name = 'gotqn';

CREATE  TABLE #T(gotqn INT)